# range copy from a column to new sheet in adjacent columns till blank cells in a loop in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel file with more than 80000 lines/values in a column. After random lines/values a blank cell is present. I want to copy all values above every blank cell to a new column in another workbook. I have tried the following,

```vb
Sub main()

Dim wba As Workbook
Dim wbb As Workbook

Set wba = Workbooks("test.xlsx")
Set wbb = Workbooks("test1.xlsx")

With wba.Worksheets("Sheet1")
      .Range("BA2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Copy
End With

wbb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

But this is copying till the occurrence of first blank cell only. I want to run it in a loop till the end of column so that if blank cell appears for say 100 times then I will have 100 columns in test1.xlsx.

The sample data is:

| A |
| --- |
| 10 |
| 20 |
| 30 |
| 4045 |
| 85 |
|  |
| 98 |
| 87 |
| 54 |
| 65 |
|  |
| 9 |
| 110 |
| 335 |
| 995 |
| 664 |
| 256 |
|  |
| 22 |
| 44 |
|  |
| 55 |
| 66 |
| 77 |

The intended output in another workbook is :

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 98 | 9 | 22 | 55 |
| 20 | 87 | 110 | 44 | 66 |
| 30 | 54 | 335 |  | 77 |
| 4045 | 65 | 995 |  |  |
| 85 |  | 664 |  |  |
|  |  | 256 |  |  |

Comment: I am not sure about your expected outcoe. Can you please read [repro] and update your question. If you use [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (instead of showing a screenshot) it is easier for us to help you.

Comment: As suggested I have used  Markdown Table Generator for sample data and intended output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but give this a try. `Areas` captures each block of cells separated by blanks. If your cells contain formulas this code will need to use `xlCellTypeFormulas` instead of `xlCellTypeConstants`.

```
Sub main()

Dim wba As Workbook
Dim wbb As Workbook
Dim r As Range, c As Long

Set wba = Workbooks("test.xlsx")
Set wbb = Workbooks("test1.xlsx")

With wba.Worksheets("Sheet1")
      For Each r In .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas
        c = c + 1
        r.Copy
        wbb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, c).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next r
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @SJR, the code is working and performing as intended.